# The number of solutions of the equation $\tan x +\sec x =2\cos x$ lying in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$ is:

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The number of solutions of the equation $\tan x +\sec x =2\cos x$ lying in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$ is:

$a$. $0$

$b$. $1$

$c$. $2$

$d$. $3$

My Attempt:
$$\tan x +\sec x=2\cos x$$
$$\dfrac {\sin x}{\cos x}+\dfrac {1}{\cos x}=2\cos x$$
$$\sin x + 1=2\cos^2 x$$
$$\sin x +1=2-2\sin^2 x$$
$$2\sin^2 x +\sin x - 1=0$$
$$2\sin^2 x +2\sin x -\sin x - 1=0$$
$$2\sin x (\sin x +1) -1(\sin x+1)=0$$
$$(\sin x +1)(2\sin x-1)=0$$

So, what's the next?

Comment: You made an error in the title

Comment: Is it $\tab \ln(x)$?

Comment: @KSplitX, Please find the edited version.

Comment: If $ab=0$ then $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Comment: @Lubin, What does this give?

Comment: Apply this principle to your last equation, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from $$(\sin x +1)(2\sin x-1)=0$$

Note it's useful to sketch the graph of $\sin x$ in the given interval:

[image]

We get that either:

$\sin x=-1\implies x=\frac{3\pi}{2},\quad$or

$\sin x =\frac{1}{2}\implies x=\frac{\pi}{6}\quad\text{or}\quad x=\frac{5\pi}{6}$

Now we must be careful since we had $\cos x$ in the denominator in the original equation, we require that $\cos x \neq 0$. This eliminates the solution $x=\frac{3\pi}{2}$. Therefore the total number of solutions is $2$ - so the answer is $(c)$.

Comment: is the total number of solutions $2$ or $3$?

Comment: @Maxwell It is $2$, I have said as much in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Obviously $x$ has possible values of $\frac{3 \pi}{2}$ (by $\sin x=-1$) and $\frac{ \pi}{6}$ , $\frac{5 \pi}{6}$ by $\sin x=\frac{1}{2}$

Now put These roots in intial conditions to verify if they satisfy it or not.

Note: $(x-a)(x-b)=0$ means $x=a$ or $x=b$

Answer (score 1):

The answer must be 2

Since tanx and secx domain would consider every x, rejecting (2n+1)π/2 values in the interval [0,2π] such values would be rejected from the solution.

In the last step sinx=1 the solution would be 3π/2 and this would be rejected due to domain condition. The other part, that is, sinx=1/2 has solution x=5π/6 and x= π/6 in the Interval [0,2π]. 
Thus the number of solutions are 2